# Illustrator brush pen pressure distortion

Tags: adobe-illustrator, brush

After a few months of using my Wacom, I started to notice that my strokes became distorted near sharp corners and curves when I changed the default 5pt brush to pen pressure.  I saw similar questions here, but the answer was to revert the stroke back to basic stroke

[image]

Is there any way to keep the pen pressure line variation, without having the distorted strokes?

Answer (score 1):

I've noticed a similar bug, but it usually only happens when you're working at a high level of zoom. Two examples where such a thing happens:

- Working at 500% zoom, using brush with pressure variance
- Working at 100% zoom, using a brush with pressure variance, and then scaling it down by roughly 20%

Try working at 100% zoom. If you need to scale down your brushstrokes without distortion, you may have to outline them by going `Object > Expand Appearance`.